# How to show instead of hide repeated values in pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets

By standard, repeated values in pivot table are only shown once. I made an example sheet to illustrate:

[image]

This becomes a problem for people who use filters over pivot tables:

[image]

Notice how Donald's sales to customer #001 disappeared?

I think this could be solved by filling the blank cells with repeated values. Is it possible to do it on Google Sheets?

Comment: Do you mind sharing that example sheet?

Comment: @404 Sure. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AxTZWq5VoeSjS0GF2xWMEKStvbgd0kRL4-aFtMU2Cjw

Comment: You can swap the order of two row groupings (drag-and-drop "Column A" about "Customer") so that different salespeople are on different lines. The larger point is, the pivot reports are not meant to be sorted or filtered like regular sheets; they have their own logic.

Comment: In the actual spreadsheet, swapping row groupings don't show all blank cells, mainly due to a large number of columns and repeated values. As a result, many rows had a lot of blank cells after filtering.

Comment: Another thing you could do is adding "Salesperson" as a column rather than a row. Then each customer has one row for their data.

Comment: @404 I got an error saying that would generate too many cells. Even if it worked, the width would be very large.

Comment: I guess the main problem here is that every column has several duplicates. None of them are made entirely of unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the filter feature (Data > Filter) add the desired field to the filter section of the pivot table report editor.

[image: Filter in pivot table report editor]

Comment: That's what I was using in Excel. The problem is Google's pivot table can't filter date ranges.

Comment: @Renan the question doesn't mention filtering date ranges in pivot tables.

Comment: I'm just saying your alternative solution is very limited compared to Excel.